# How to extract live data from PC games

Tags: database, interactive

Let's assume that I'm playing a game on PC, most likely off-line. Is it possible for me to design a code that can interact with this game? For example, if I'm playing Fifa, can I implement a VB code, or any other language, that can print the score, or the name of the player who has the ball at a moment.

Is it possible? If so, how to do it, or at least in what field should I start looking for the answer (the write words for the search)?

Comment: This is outside the scope of StackOverflow. I recommend you read [how to ask a good question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player names and live stats can be read from the memory that the games uses on your system.

If you look into searching in memory for a player name or another ingame value you might be able to identify the addressing the game uses.

A lot of game trainers / hacks n such read / write to the memory space the game uses.